In Rails 7, how to render Chartkick chart with a Javascript function inside the options?
I want to use Chartkick to visualize data. My basic code looks like this:
<%= line_chart [{ name: "Weather forecast",
                      data: @dataset
               }],
               {
                 defer: true,
               }
%>

In this case, the basic chart is render - all good.
Now, I would like to modify the labels on the y-axis:
<%= line_chart [{ name: "Weather forecast",
                  data: @dataset
               }],
               {
                 defer: true,
                 yaxis: {
                   labels: {
                   formatter: function(val, opts) {
                                return val;
                              }
                   }
                },
        }
%>

And here comes the problem - executing this code results in the following error:
undefined local variable or method `val' for #<ActionView::Base:0x00000000150590>

I also tried the following modification:
<%= line_chart [{ name: "Weather forecast",
                  data: @dataset
               }],
               {
                 defer: true,
                 yaxis: {
                   labels: {
                   formatter: raw("function(val, opts) {
                                return val;
                              }")
                   }
                },
        }
%>

Which removed the previous error and rendered page successfully, BUT without the chart and in the browser console is the following error:
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.w.config.yaxis[e].labels.formatter is not a function

How do I fix this? The purpose of the code in the formatter block is to format the numbers.
